# What is the name of the library to generate such an image

Tags: python

Often on the Internet I saw such images and now I am interested in the implementation of this algorithm. The input is a template and a set of words, on the basis of which the image is drawn, the more often the word is used the more space it takes. As far as I know there is already a library for python that allows you to generate such images. Could you tell me which one?[image]

Comment: They are commonly know used to build word cloud. You can google word cloud images. In python there `word_cloud` package to make your task easy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Word cloud allows you to do this, and using its masks features should allow you to shape them: https://github.com/amueller/word_cloud would give you more information on how this can be done.

Answer (score 0):

The above image is constructed using wordCloud!. [Here](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/wordcloud-python) you can find a tutorial on python.

I hope this helps...